# Data merge by using sql query with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query and it returns 48 records by multiple joins but I want it merge and make it 4 records as shown in below.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd9vr.png]

Comment: Show us your query that you have tried. In this way people will be able to help you faster. Also, check this hint: GROUP BY.

Comment: Please don't use images. Show us the table structures, sample data and expected output in Text form.

Comment: I don't know how you will get Org Admin in there since it doesn't appear in the top group.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think your expected results are going to happen given the variability of your sample data.  The simplest form of what you are looking for is:

```sql
SELECT t.username, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.email_address, ... t.org_name,
       listagg(t.permission_id||':'||t.permission, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.permission_id)
FROM table_name t
GROUP BY t.username, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.email_address, ... t.org_name;
```

Obviously the ellipsis (...) isn't going to work, but your screenshot doesn't show all of the full column names.